# Track 2 views of 1 page

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I need to set up a new goal in Google Analytics which will be executed when 1 unique visitor views 2 different articles.

For example, I have a thousands of different articles:
/page/article_water.html
/page/article_google_analytics.html
....
....
...
/page/article_another_one.html

So, a Google Analytics URL-pattern of this page will looks like this:

.*/page/article_.*.html

The thing is, that I need to catch up 2 views of different articles with similar URL.

Have no idea how to do that, Google didn't help me.

Comment: Does not work with goals. You can create a sequence type segment to filter out those visitors, but there are no multistep goals (makes one hope that on day you can have goals based on segments, but as of now it's impossible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alexander**, what you cou do is to check whether the articles were seen on your backend and if so, send an event to Google Analytics that will trigger the goal completion (event-based goal).

Or try setting up two different goals and then create a segment that will filter those users/visitors. Could work as well.

Comment: Thanks, Petr. It will work if i need only to filter out such users in GA reports. But my main purpose is to start remarketing for them, so it must be a goal somehow.

Comment: Have looked their API for collecting data via my backend. As i understood, i must provide unique id for each user for each API request, but there is no obvious possibility of providing inner-analytics id of user visiting the page, only generated by my backend. So it will not help in this case.

Comment: Alex, I was thinking something more simple might do - store articles IDs seen during a session and of those required were seen, trigger a simple GA event. Then create 1 goal that will be accomplished if such event was sent.

Comment: Yeah, Peter, forgot to post it here - did it exactly as you answered :) worked fine for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Done :) pretty clear solution. Sometimes you must simplify your way of thinking to solve a problem ))